# Microblink: Extracting the issuer name

Tags: ios, microblink

Although we were able to do this Android, we haven't yet got the issuer name on iOS.

```
// after Microblink has looked at an image (from the camera roll)
func recognizerRunner(_ recognizerRunner: MBCRecognizerRunner, didFinishScanningWith state: MBCRecognizerResultState) {
    if state == .valid { // values: .empty, .uncertain, .valid, .stageValid
        let result = blinkCardRecognizer.result
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
            let details = VerificationDetails(firstSix: self.firstSix(result.cardNumber),
                                              lastFour: self.lastFour(result.cardNumber),
                                              name: result.owner,
                                              brand: result.issuer)
            self.delegate?.scanningSuccess(details: details)
        })
    }
    else {
        self.delegate?.scanningFailed()
    }
}
```

The problem is that `result.issuer` is returning a `MBCIssuer` object, which I can't find any documentation for. How do I retrieve a string from a `MBCIssuer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. Available from:
`MBCBlinkCardUtils.issuer(toString: result.issuer)`

Comment: Hi @coco, apologies for the delay. 
Yes, you are correct, you need to use MBCBlinkCardUtils utils method in order to return the issuer string from the MBCIssuer enum. :)